# Add a new column rank, this new column should have a rank based on transaction_day and percentage of total

Tags: sql

For the ranking, the split should be as follows:

- For the most recent transactions aggregating to 30% the rank should be 5
- For the next transactions aggregating to 20% the rank should be 4
- For the later aggregating to 25% the rank should be 3
- For the later aggregating to 25% the rank should be 2
- For the next 20% the rank should be 1

Here is the query

```
    WITH LatestTransactions AS (
  SELECT
    member_id,
    MAX(sales_date) AS last_transaction_date
  FROM
    core.pos_transactions_test
  WHERE 
    sales_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 YEAR' 
    AND loyalty_sale = 1 AND ethical_sale = 0 AND transaction_type = 'Sales'
  GROUP BY
    member_id
),
SalesDataWithRowNumber AS (
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(lt.last_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS transaction_day,
    COUNT(*) AS sale_count,
    ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()), 2) AS percentage_of_total,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(lt.last_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS row_number
  FROM
    core.pos_transactions_test AS t
  JOIN
    LatestTransactions AS lt ON t.member_id = lt.member_id AND t.sales_date = lt.last_transaction_date
  WHERE 
    t.sales_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 YEAR' 
    AND t.loyalty_sale = 1 AND t.ethical_sale = 0 AND t.transaction_type = 'Sales' 
  GROUP BY 
    TO_CHAR(lt.last_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
)
SELECT
  transaction_day,
  sale_count,
  percentage_of_total,
  row_number
FROM
  SalesDataWithRowNumber
ORDER BY
  transaction_day;
```

Comment: Please do not spam the tag. Tag only the database that you are using

Comment: I removed the spammed tags... please add back the single RDBMS you are using. Also we need a [MRE] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please look at this https://dbfiddle.uk/RxCeL1dT Trying to understand but the problem is you haven't provided sample data or the expected result.